# electron-builder - how to auto-update from github tags if program does not use semver?

Tags: electron-builder, electron-updater

- electron-builder and its electron-updater dictate that program must have semver
- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/v23.0.3/packages/electron-updater/src/AppUpdater.ts#L331

how to point autoUpdater to take any tag - given it is the latest tag - and update?

Answer (score 0):

solution

- take off heavy elecron - use full jvm .jar programs with swing ui instead